# dc.js: can't change number of child charts of composite

Tags: dc.js

I have a stackchart grouped by year, but when I would filter another chart and reduce the number of selected days, it should regroup by month or day.

This seems to work for me looking at this example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yccu/du10hzvq/2/).

Now I'm trying to add a line chart on the second axis, and use the compose functionality but getting lost now as it does not seem to replace charts but adding it up, example in  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yccu/du10hzvq/1/)

It should all be regrouping depending on the number of days that are selected.

```
 .on("filtered", function(chart, filter){   
        if(filter.length > 0) {
        var max_date = d3.time.month.ceil(filter[1]);
        var min_date = d3.time.month.floor(filter[0]);
        var days = (max_date - min_date) / 86400000;

            if(days<163){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few other issues, but I'll address the one you asked.

Currently the composite chart does not support adding and removing child charts with just a redraw. You'll have to render the chart when changing its children.

```
       StackBarByMonth.render()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/z9tm81ng/10/

There is another issue where the domain change doesn't work until you set the filter small enough to switch to days, but I didn't have any luck with that. At least it seems to work consistently at any any scale after having first shown days.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, again thanks for your help! This works I just wanted to answer my own question until I saw your solution. Using $(".sub").remove()  works but your solution is better.

Comment: as for your last note, I had to play with the number of days and probably need to finetune it a bit more, correct the xAxisPadding (https://jsfiddle.net/du10hzvq/4/)

Comment: Glad to help! That's a nice looking dashboard.